# How to get autoconfigured kafkaTransactionManager in a consumer app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

[KafkaAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/kafka/KafkaAutoConfiguration.java#L112) has `kafkaTransactionManager` bean configured only if "spring.kafka.producer.transaction-id-prefix" property is set.

Is it ok to set this property for obtaining this autoconfigured bean in an application that just consumes data from a topic and doesn't have any producer logic?

I'm going to implement 1pc best effort pattern in my consumer app, so I need to have both `kafkaTransactionManager` and `JpaTransactionManager` in the context to use them with `@Transactional` annotations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't use a producer side, then you don't need this `KafkaTransactionManager`. Just inject that `JpaTransactionManager` into the `ContainerProperties`:

```
/**
 * Set the transaction manager to start a transaction; offsets are committed with
 * semantics equivalent to {@link AckMode#RECORD} and {@link AckMode#BATCH} depending
 * on the listener type (record or batch).
 * @param transactionManager the transaction manager.
 * @since 1.3
 * @see #setAckMode(AckMode)
 */
public void setTransactionManager(@Nullable PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
```

Comment: Don't we need to use smth like `ChainedTransactionManager` here or so in this case?

Comment: No. That one has been deprecated. The `KafkaTransactionManager` is an artificial solution and makes sense only if you try to do receive-n-forward use-case as a single unit of work. The situation when both consumer and producer are involved. The rest of scenarios simply could be done via normal transactions and their synchronizations.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! The next one is probably not really related to the topic, but do you know if it's possible to configure `ContainerProperties` via Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Binder abstraction?

Comment: I only see this `KafkaConsumerProperties.getTransactionManager()` option. Not sure what drove them to rely only on the `KafkaAwareTransactionManager`...

Comment: Just use `@Transactional` on the listener; there is no need to inject it into the container. The container TM is only needed for Kafka transactions (so the container can send the offsets to the transaction).